# Angular2: Passing object from @CanActivate() into component -> Typescript Error

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular 2 I have a `MyObjectComponent` that shows an array of `myObjects`. I get this `myObjects` from a `MyObjectService` which is invoked by `@CanActivate`.

```
@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {

    let myObjectService: MyObjectService = //get my ObjectService here....

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        myObjectService.getMyObjects()
            .subscribe((myObjects) => {
               next.params['myObjects'] = myObjects;
               resolve(true);
             });
    })
```

In my component I get the data via

```
routerOnActivate(next) {
    this.myComponentObjectVariable = next.params.myObjects;
}
```

This works, but only if the `myObjects` that I add to `next.params['myObjects']` is a string.

If I add an object I will get a

> Typescript error: TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

However, the resulting JavaScript works as expected. But I want to get rid of the Typescript error message.

The error results because of the definition of the params object in `ComponentInstruction`:

```
declare class ComponentInstruction {
    ... some other data ...
    params: {
        [key: string]: string;
    }; 
}
```

Of course I can change the class `ComponentInstruction` but that would be a bit ugly.

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 1):

`params` is supposed to be treated as immutable.

I'd suggest you use the approach demonstrated in the Plunker linked to in this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572 and pass the value using a shared service instead of route params.

An alternative way is to use

`_router.navigate(...)` and pass custom route parameters there.

For this case you also would need the approach demonstrated in the Plunker to get the applications `Router` instance.

Comment: My aim is to resolve data before routing. This was possible in Angular1 with `resolve` in the route definition.  

So I have to create a new service. This new service receives the data from `@CanActivate()` and `@CanActivate()` resolves the promise when the process of storing has finished. Then I can use in `MyComponent` the new service without waiting for the data.

Isn't this a bit overkill? If I have different types of `MyObjects` in my application, I will have to write for every type a special service to share the data. Or a general service for all `MyObjects` without type safety.

Comment: The Angular team is aware that the router has serious limitations. The router is work in progress. There are lots of changes to be expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I tried the solution with a service to share the data. I hope there will be another solution available soon.